# Content versioning - auto save is not compatible with event sourcing

Tags: versioning, event-sourcing, autosave

I'd like to version some articles so the authors will be able to restore previous versions if they want. The articles contain additional contents, for example images which I don't want to version, just save on the server. I'd like to have drafts, which can be overridden and I'd like to have a commit system. So if a draft is committed, then a new content version should be created on the server. I'd like to auto-save these drafts on the server, so they can be synchronized between clients. How should I solve auto-saving without polluting the event storage with a huge amount of draft auto-save events?

I guess I'll need some GC logic for the event storage to invalidate previous draft auto-saves after saving a new one. Is there an already existing solution for that, or should I code this for myself?

Comment: Do simultaneous users work on the same draft?

Comment: I mean, what happens when two users (auto)save the same draft at the same time?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU No, only the owner can modify a draft. If you commit a draft, you will get a new version of the article. Other authors will be able to begin with that version and create a new draft based on it. Or they can merge versions manually with a diff tool.

Comment: The you should keep the editing/auto-saving outside the Event sourcing and use simple CRUD.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Drafts should be synced between the computers of the author. So they should be able to use multiple different computers (not concurrently) to edit the articles. How can I solve this without saving the drafts on the server? And if I save them on the server I will save them in the event storage as well. I guess...

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use CRUD and generate a domain event every time a draft is updated that should be pushed to the other clients so that they poll the new draft. The event should be something like this: `DraftUpdated(id, timestamp)`; this domain event should not be stored in the event store.

Comment: Please tell me if you need more details

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Thanks! That's funny, I did not know that there can be domain events which aren't saved in the storage. :D

Comment: These events are widely used in CQRS (without ES) architectures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be two separate bounded contexts: `Editing bounded context` and `Content bounded context` (names may differ, please adapt to your domain).

In the `Editing BC` you should not use `Event sourcing` as the persistence mechanism of the drafts. Instead you could use simple `CRUD` entities and publish an infrastructure event (i.e. `DraftUpdated(id, timestamp)`) every time the `Draft` is persisted (i.e. auto-save). Then, an event listener should forward that event to the connected clients so that they update their version of the draft. This infrastructure event should not be persisted, it's just a transient event. You could use any transport mechanism available like [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Comment: I may have found another way. I store the `DraftUpdated` event in a temporary storage which persists the event in the event storage after a while, e.g. 10 mins. Every time autosave updates the draft, the event saved in the temporary storage will be overridden and the timer resets. This way the draft saving won't be that frequent, I can sync drafts with other clients, and the event storage can still be used. I just need to try out this in practice.